# Take a balanced sample of characters from a list of variable length tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing

I have a large list of over N = 1e7 variable length tuples. I want to use python to sample tuples from the list such that the concatenated tuples have K balanced characters. They may be multiple solutions, but I just want one solution.

Here is a simplified example. Say I want K = 4 from this list of tuples:

```
[ ('C', 'A', 'D'),
  ('D', 'E', 'A'),
  ('A', 'D', 'C', 'E'),
  ('D', 'B', 'A', 'B'),
  ('B', 'C'),
  ('B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C'),
  ('E', 'B', 'C'),
  ('E', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'E'),
  ('B', 'E', 'E', 'A'),
  ('A', 'D') ]
```

One solution has these indexes:

```
[0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

Which has corresponding values:

```
[ ('C', 'A', 'D'),
  ('A', 'D', 'C', 'E'),
  ('B', 'C'),
  ('B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C'),
  ('B', 'E', 'E', 'A'),
  ('A', 'D') ]
```

Sorted and concatenated, the solution is clearly balanced:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 
 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 
 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']
```

My idea was to randomly sample tuples from the list until one of the characters totaled K = 4. Then, sample from the subset of remaining tuples that did not have the character. However, if there are no valid subsets, this means we would need to redo the original sample... potentially infinitely.

Is there a solution that is expected to finish in a reasonable number of finite steps?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: this site is more for code questions than algorithm questions, it's a fascinating problem though

Comment: @Anentropic While it's more for code questions, algorithms questions are valid and are asked and answered daily.

Comment: How many distinct characters are there?

Comment: This is known as [exact set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). There is no easy solution.

Comment: In my case, there are 40 distinct characters. In this example, there are 5 distinct characters.

Comment: The solution does not need to be exact, but I will look into set covers...

Comment: Can the solution be flexible on "K" (meaning we could get K +- epsilon characters), "Balanced" (meaning some counts may differ by epsilon) or both?

Comment: It is okay for the solution to have K +/- Epsilon of each class

Comment: There is probably an error in your example. The required indexes must be [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9] - not [0, 2, 4, 5, 9]

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have revised the example.